# Disallow numbers divided not equally in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

There is table of records, where columns are 12 month + summary.
I have simple jQuery action which `onChange` of summary row divide number equaly for each month.

Because it's accounting stuff I round number to .00 and store it in DB.
I want to disallow entering numbers which are not dividable by 12.

**Unfortunatelly my algorithm has a flaws :/**

**(ex. entering 11, changes to 11.08 != 12 * 0.93)**

```
function round(num) {
    return Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100;
}

$("#summary").change(function() {
    var summaryValue = $(this).val();
    var monthCount = $('.month').length;

    var remainder = (summaryValue * 100) % monthCount;
    summaryValue = (summaryValue * 100 + remainder) / 100; 
    $(this).val(summaryValue);    

    var avarage = round(summaryValue / monthCount);

    $('.month').each( function( key, value ) {
        $(this).val(avarage);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/igos/z3EEQ/

Any ideas how to implement it better?

1. By dividable by 12 I mean, every number allow is devided with max 2
   numbers after coma.
2. So 11 will be changed to 11,04 because 0.92 * 12 = 11.04;
3. 1324 => 1324,08 = 110,34*12
4. I can not say: bad number, because I want to offer to user closest number to which he originally wanted to enter.

Comment: Can you just add an if-statement, something like `if (number % 12 != 0) { //not a good number }`

Comment: I guess everything can be dividable by 12. Do you mean it should not be a floating point number or what?

Comment: what do you want to happen when 11 is entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subtract the remainder. If you want the number closest to the original, then subtract the remainder AND add 12 IF the remainder is greater than 6:

```
var remainder = (summaryValue * 100) % monthCount;
summaryValue = (summaryValue * 100 - remainder + (remainder > 6? 12 : 0)) / 100;
```